# Is there a method to post-process a Fairplay encrypted stream on iOS

Tags: ios, video, post-processing, fairplay

On iOS 13, I'm looking at how/if I can take a fairplay-encrypted HEVC Main10 stream, and post-process the decoded frames before display.  I'd like to use the on-board HEVC hardware decoder.  In other environments (e.g. Windows), I can code sign an MFT and have it in the rendering chain for DRM content.

I cannot find a similar function in iOS documentation, but this could be my fail...

Answer (score 1):

No. The FairPlay system controls access to pixel data from network to display. Giving access to raw pixel data is exactly what FairPlay is trying to prevent.

Comment: Understood - my comment above is that Windows DRM allows a lib signed with a microsoft-issued key (under contractual obligations) to sit in the render chain.  No such thing in Fairplay?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But maybe